# How to stop negative lookahead failure while having an optional string before it?

Tags: regex, vba

I'm working on a VBA macro and I need to use regex in it, but `Regex.Test()` gives me weird results.

I want it to return False if it finds `c` after a `b` which is optional, in the string `abcd`. I tried the following pattern:

```
ab?(?!c)
```

But it returns True.

I've tried to research it and I think it's because of backtracking, since `ab?(?!c)d` returns False as expected. But the problem is that I don't know what will come after `c`, if anything. But trying to use anything nonspecific like `ab?(?!c).` is also True for some reason.

I have also read about the atomic feature for lookaround, but it just confused me more.

Comment: You probably need `a(?!bc)b?`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Yxe9f/1).

Comment: IF string regex matches `bc` THEN fail ELSE success

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That would fail for inputs like "abdbc" which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: @41686d6564 Why do you say that? OP stated "If `c` comes after `b` then fail." By leverage the power of negation a regex of `bc` will detect the existence of this non-desirable pattern.

Comment: Well, taking into account the pattern is used in a `.Test()` method, the `bc` check might really be sufficient to solve the issue (and no regex is actually required then). If you want to match `a` not followed with `bc` or `c`, you may simply use `a(?!b?c)` or `a(?!c)(?!bc)`. Consuming the optional `b` only makes sense if you *extract* or *replace* matches. And note that `a(?!b?c)` will find a match in `adac`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's how I understood it as well. The leading `a` and trailing `d` seem to be inconsequential to the goal.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Indeed, if the OP only wants to prevent "bc" anywhere. They could also just use `InStr(input, "bc") <> 0`; no need for regex then. Although it's a possibility, I do not think that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yep! Hopefully OP is still around and can clear up the confusion...

Comment: @deviance Please don't edit the question to add comments like "solved" or "thanks" (See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829/8967612)). Accepting an answer (which you did) is enough indication that it solved your problem. That being said, you're welcome. I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that because `b` is optional, the matching will succeed as long as it finds `a` (it will only include `b` if it's not followed by `c`).

You need something like the following:

```
a(?!bc)b?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Yxe9f/1/)**.

The trick here is to make sure that `a` is not followed by `bc`. In other words, tie the condition to `a`, not `b` because the latter is optional and can be ignored when the condition fails.

If you want the match to also fail if `c` is found immediately after `a` as well (i.e., without `b`), just change the pattern to:

```
a(?!b?c)b?
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o8t8br/1)**.